# For every positive integer $n, n^2 + 4n + 3$ is not a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove:
For every positive integer $n, n^2 + 4n + 3$ is not a prime.

I tried to disprove the statement, which I could not using several number examples with constructive proof.

However I am not sure how to correctly step by step prove it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is $$(n+1)(n+3)$$ and thus not prime because it has to factors greater than one.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:
$$n^2+ 4n+3=(n+1)(n+3)$$

Comment: YEs got it! thats basically what I needed!

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $n^2+4n+3 = (n+1)(n+3)$. Can you take it further?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $n^2 + 4n + 3 = (n + 1)(n + 3)$. Since $n$ is necessarily a positive integer, it is obvious that $n^2 + 4n + 3$ is composite.

Comment: What is it that your answer adds to the other three answers?